# Joomla menu item type issue

Tags: menu-item

We are trying to create Joomla menu item, which works fine on other live servers except my web server.

1. We have to go to menu manager, and create menu and create menu item.

[image]

2. Then click select.

[image]

3. We need to select Article so click on & select Single Article.

   [image]
4. After Selecting Single Article, this shows menu item type and link for selecting article but here it is not showing.

[image]

Kindly help me!!!

Comment: Hi, really hard to help as it is something that always work, Some tips, * enable joomla debug and also error reporting to develpoment   * Do you have a template override for articles?    *  Please clean joomla cache and also your browser cache

Comment: more ideas: Do you have articles? do you have articles in the menu language? Update Joomla to latest 3.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found solution from joomla forum 
Thanks Everyone.

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=702182

Comment: Welcome to Joomla Stack Exchange, @swapnil. Please post the complete solution here, as links may break, and the link provided does not give a clear answer. It might help other users with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

This process works fine on other live servers but not on your **local installation** or your live web server?

In both cases, this to do with your server set-up.

First of all, you need to make sure that it is running a compatible version of PHP.

Then, you need to look at the System Information on the version of the site that is working and on the one that is not working. This may give you more clues about set-up differences that are causing issue.

Comment: The process works fine on other liver server but not on our live web server